# Cocos 2d build crash

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, testflight, crash-log

I'm developing a cocos2d iphone 3.0 game. Yesterday I've uploaded it to testflight and they rejected it because it crashes as soon as it starts.

This is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: D468C8A5-056A-424C-A55C-2E9DDC9AA71D
CrashReporter Key:   1c7ceb385551765c2a8424e10a9353f1bebfdd32
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             HeadIt [2764]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4A7E6750-A6DC-45BB-B57A-4DC448CF0B5F/HeadIt.app/HeadIt
Identifier:          com.moonideas.juegoPrueba
Version:             3 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-03-03 12:11:05.05 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-03-03 12:11:05.05 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D20)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Breadcrumb Trail: (reverse chronological seconds)
0      GC Framework: startAuthenticationForExistingPrimaryPlayer


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ad0140 0x181ab4000 + 115008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181b98ef8 0x181b94000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181a41dac 0x1819e0000 + 400812
3   HeadIt                          0x00000001000cf820 -[CCGLProgram addAttribute:index:] (CCGLProgram.m:193)
4   HeadIt                          0x00000001000cf494 -[CCGLProgram initWithVertexShaderByteArray:fragmentShaderByteArray:] (CCGLProgram.m:110)
5   HeadIt                          0x00000001000aeb44 -[CCShaderCache loadDefaultShaders] (CCShaderCache.m:196)
6   HeadIt                          0x00000001000ae5f8 -[CCShaderCache init] (CCShaderCache.m:79)
7   HeadIt                          0x00000001000ae4c4 +[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] (CCShaderCache.m:42)
8   HeadIt                          0x00000001001229ac -[CCTexture initWithData:pixelFormat:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:contentSizeInPixels:contentScale:] (CCTexture.m:234)
9   HeadIt                          0x00000001001233d0 -[CCTexture(Image) initWithCGImage:contentScale:] (CCTexture.m:534)
10  HeadIt                          0x0000000100072740 -[CCDirector createStatsLabel] (CCDirector.m:840)
11  HeadIt                          0x00000001000d576c -[CCDirectorIOS setProjection:] (CCDirectorIOS.m:216)
12  HeadIt                          0x0000000100070fc8 -[CCDirector setGLDefaultValues] (CCDirector.m:217)
13  HeadIt                          0x0000000100071318 -[CCDirector setView:] (CCDirector.m:344)
14  HeadIt                          0x00000001000d59f4 -[CCDirectorIOS setView:] (CCDirectorIOS.m:262)
15  HeadIt                          0x000000010007d4d0 -[CCAppDelegate setupCocos2dWithOptions:] (CCAppDelegate.m:205)
16  HeadIt                          0x0000000100110954 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:34)
17  UIKit                           0x0000000186c95704 0x186c0c000 + 562948
18  UIKit                           0x0000000186ec4130 0x186c0c000 + 2851120
19  UIKit                           0x0000000186ec84b8 0x186c0c000 + 2868408
20  UIKit                           0x0000000186ec55c0 0x186c0c000 + 2856384
21  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001834e3790 0x1834bc000 + 161680
22  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001834e3b10 0x1834bc000 + 162576
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ee4efc 0x181e08000 + 904956
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ee4990 0x181e08000 + 903568
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ee2690 0x181e08000 + 894608
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181e11680 0x181e08000 + 38528
27  UIKit                           0x0000000186c8e580 0x186c0c000 + 533888
28  UIKit                           0x0000000186c88d90 0x186c0c000 + 511376
29  HeadIt                          0x00000001000d09c4 main (main.m:14)
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001819b28b8 0x1819b0000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.gamecenter.GKDaemonProxy
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ab54f8 0x181ab4000 + 5368
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181992a38 0x181980000 + 76344
2   GameCenterFoundation            0x000000018f993ad0 0x18f938000 + 375504
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181981630 0x181980000 + 5680
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001819815f0 0x181980000 + 5616
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018198d634 0x181980000 + 54836
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001819850f4 0x181980000 + 20724
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001819815f0 0x181980000 + 5616
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018198fa88 0x181980000 + 64136
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018198f224 0x181980000 + 61988
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181b95470 0x181b94000 + 5232
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181b95020 0x181b94000 + 4128

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ad14fc 0x181ab4000 + 120060
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018199494c 0x181980000 + 84300
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001819837bc 0x181980000 + 14268

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ad0b6c 0x181ab4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181b95530 0x181b94000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181b95020 0x181b94000 + 4128

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ad0b6c 0x181ab4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181b95530 0x181b94000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181b95020 0x181b94000 + 4128

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fda1cf7
    x4: 0x000000016fda18d0   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x31343a39323a3931   x7: 0x0000000000000660
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000003c57  x11: 0x00000001a1cc1661
   x12: 0x00000001a1cc1661  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x000000008000001f  x15: 0x0000000080000023
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001001781a0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019f81f000  x21: 0x000000010015f0fd  x22: 0x0000000000000010  x23: 0x0000000000000018
   x24: 0x0000000000000014  x25: 0x0000000187602d97  x26: 0x000000012cf65610  x27: 0x000000012ce86520
   x28: 0x0000000000000008  fp: 0x000000016fda1880   lr: 0x0000000181b98ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fda1860   pc: 0x0000000181ad0140 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

The weird thing is that apparently it falls when the app is configuring cocos2d:

```
 15  HeadIt 0x000000010007d4d0 -[CCAppDelegate setupCocos2dWithOptions:] (CCAppDelegate.m:205)
```

I didn't change anything of Cocos2d. Has anyone ever experienced this? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: DId you ever try to test it on the real device or update to 3.4.9?

Comment: You need to symbolicate the stacktrace and post the code where the crash occurs.

Comment: On a bad day, Game Center Authentication will hang your app and crash it. This is most common in iOS 9